# python3 duckduckgo_search user input search type

Tags: python-3.x

Currently writing a script to save DuckDuckGo search results to a CSV file. The script below functions but only with ddgs.text. What I'm searching for is a way to user define what follows the dot. Such as ddgs.news or ddgs.images ect. Any assistance appreciated. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# TITLE:DDG_text.py
# RELEVANT URL:https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo-search/#1-text---text-search-by-duckduckgocom
# DATE:10 November 2023
# PURPOSE:Search DuckDuckGo for text

from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
import csv

s = input("Enter search string: \n")
n = int(input("Enter number of results: \n"))
x = input("Enter name of csv file with extension: \n")

csv_file = open(x, "w")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")

with DDGS() as ddgs:
    results = [r for r in ddgs.text(s, max_results=n)]

for x in range(len(results)):
    row = [results[x]["title"], results[x]["body"], results[x]["href"]]
    writer.writerow(row)

csv_file.close()
```

web searches turned up little of value. Adding a variable after the ddgs. results in an error.

```
Also tried writing a function
```